# Bulk delete users in identity server via Management Console

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to delete all users in an identity server using Management Console.

Individual user delete is possible from Management console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete a set of users via management console is not supported.

But SCIM2 supports bulk user deletion.

You can use the following command to delete a set users. This is similar to bulk user creation via SCIM2 api. You can refer to this doc for [scim2 bulk user creation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/using-the-scim-2.0-rest-apis/#bulk-endpoint).

```
 curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data '{"failOnErrors":2,"schemas":["urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"],"Operations":[{"path":"/Users/{user_scim_id}","method":"DELETE"},{"path":"/Users/{user_scim_id}","method":"DELETE"}]}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Bulk
```

**Sample request:**

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data '{"failOnErrors":2,"schemas":["urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"],"Operations":[{"path":"/Users/0a72621e-1bf2-492f-8e22-4dcfc25b607b","method":"DELETE"},{"path":"/Users/557b598d-becf-49c1-a043-8a4bd492f447","method":"DELETE"}]}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Bulk
```

You can refer to this [blog](https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/scim-bulk-endpoint-operations-in-wso2-identity-server/) for further information on bulk user deletion and this [git issue](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/3275)

adding postman collection

[image: Run in Postman]